# Nautilus doesn't show ownership change after `chmod`

Tags: command-line, ownership

I have been trying to change the ownership of a folder from "root" to "caleb" (the user).  When I attempt to change it in the terminal, it states that it has been changed, but when I look at the properties of that folder in Nautilus, it is still owned by root.

#### Terminal changes ownership

```
caleb@Caleb-Linux:~$ sudo chown caleb -v /opt
[sudo] password for caleb:
changed owndership of '/opt' from root to caleb
```

Output of `ls -ld`:

```
caleb@Caleb-Linux:~$ ls -ld /opt
ddrwxrwx--- 4 caleb caleb 4096 May 10 21:37 /opt
```

#### But Nautilus doesn't show ownership change

[image: Nautilus doesn't show ownership change]

Comment: What appears when you do:
ls -l

Comment: I just tried it, and my file browser Nautilus wasn't showing the ownership change until I hit CRTL-R, which refreshed the root folder contents/info.  Then the file browser showed the new ownership.

Comment: Why do you need to change the ownership of `/opt` why not change the ownership of a subfolder instead?

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen I use a lot of folders in /opt but i dont have ownership of /opt also I want access to it...why shouldnt i have access to it?

Comment: Your `ls -l` listing doesn't show opt. You changed the ownership of the `/opt` directory itself. What does `ls -ld /opt` show?  And, please, do not post **raster screen captures** of **text**!

Comment: @Kaz it says "drwxrwx--- 4 caleb caleb 4096 May 10 21:37 /opt
"

Comment: The subfolders of `/opt` should have their ownership changed not the main `/opt` folder, remember that that folder is used by the system.

Answer (score 1):

Your command changes the permissions of the `/opt` directory, but not its contents. To verify that the ownership is changed, use:

```
ls -ld /opt
```

If you forget the `-d`, this will list the contents of `/opt`, not the `/opt` object itself.

If you want to change the ownership not only of `/opt` itself but everything it contains, you need the `-r` (recursive) option on `chown`.

As to the GUI not showing the updated ownership of `/opt`; that could just be from it not re-reading the filesystem and relying on previously scanned information.

On Ubuntu 17.10, I can easily reproduce what I think you're running into. When I open the root directory ("Computer") in Nautilus, and right click on "opt" then view the "Properties", it's owned by root. If I change the ownership to myself in the shell, then of course this window doesn't change. If I close the Properties window and then right click on "opt" again to view the properties, it still indicates that it's owned by root.

**To get Nautilus to re-read the latest meta-data and show the up-to-date permissions, hit Ctrl-R to refresh. Or else navigate to another folder and back.**